# connect to node shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, node-connections

i adjusted some code but now i reached my borders.
i'd want to rotate the following shape with 90 degree, so it looks upwards afterwards.
[image]
[image]

but my problem is to put the connection lines also from west to north. It seems this shape doesn't have the anchor i need for this. 
My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{flowchart}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning, shapes, matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\newcommand{\mysize}{2.5cm}
\newcommand{\connectlength}{0.6cm}




\tikzstyle{mynode}=[draw, minimum size=\mysize,
label={[anchor = east]25:$\text{A}$},
label={[anchor = east]-25:$\text{B}$},]

\tikzstyle{mynodemirror} = [draw, minimum size=\mysize,
    label={[anchor = west]155:$\text{A}$},
    label={[anchor = west]205:$\text{B}$},]

\tikzstyle{mynodebelow} = [draw, minimum size=\mysize,
    label={[anchor = north]110:$\text{A}$},
    label={[anchor = north]70:$\text{B}$}]
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    % Hilfslinien
%   \draw[help lines] (0,-7) grid (7,7);
    \node[mynode] (master) {node 0};
    \node[mynodemirror, right=8cm of master] (slave1)  {node 1};
    \node[mynodebelow, below left=2.0cm of slave1] (slave2)  {node 2};
%   \node[vcc, above=2cm of slave1]          (nodevcc) {VCC};


    \draw ($(master.north east)!.5!(master.east)$) to[short,-o]  ++(\connectlength,0) coordinate (oben_master);
    \draw ($(master.south east)!.5!(master.east)$) to[short,-o] ++(\connectlength,0) coordinate (unten_master);


    \draw ($(slave1.north west)!.5!(slave1.west)$) to[short,-o]  ++(-\connectlength,0) coordinate (oben_slave1);
    \draw ($(slave1.south west)!.5!(slave1.west)$) to[short,-o] ++(-\connectlength,0) coordinate (unten_slave1);

    % how to change the following line to make the connections look upwards?
    \draw ($(slave2.north west)!.5!(slave2.west)$) to[short,-o]  ++(-\connectlength,0) coordinate (oben_slave2);
    \draw ($(slave2.south west)!.5!(slave2.west)$) to[short,-o] ++(-\connectlength,0) coordinate (unten_slave2);



    \draw (oben_master) to[short] (oben_slave1);
    \draw (unten_master) to[short](unten_slave1);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

results in this:

[image]

my try to fix `node 2`-shape (but can't compile)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{flowchart}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning, shapes, matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\newcommand{\mysize}{2.5cm}
\newcommand{\connectlength}{0.6cm}




\tikzstyle{mynode}=[draw, minimum size=\mysize,
label={[anchor = east]25:$\text{A}$},
label={[anchor = east]-25:$\text{B}$},]

\tikzstyle{mynodemirror} = [draw, minimum size=\mysize,
    label={[anchor = west]155:$\text{A}$},
    label={[anchor = west]205:$\text{B}$},]

\tikzstyle{mynodebelow} = [draw, minimum size=\mysize,
    label={[anchor = north]110:$\text{A}$},
    label={[anchor = north]70:$\text{B}$}]
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    % Hilfslinien
%   \draw[help lines] (0,-7) grid (7,7);
    \node[mynode] (master) {node 0};
    \node[mynodemirror, right=8cm of master] (slave1)  {node 1};
    \node[mynodebelow, below left=2.0cm of slave1] (slave2)  {node 2};
%   \node[vcc, above=2cm of slave1]          (nodevcc) {VCC};


    \draw ($(master.north east)!.5!(master.east)$) to[short,-o]  ++(\connectlength,0) coordinate (oben_master);
    \draw ($(master.south east)!.5!(master.east)$) to[short,-o] ++(\connectlength,0) coordinate (unten_master);


    \draw ($(slave1.north west)!.5!(slave1.west)$) to[short,-o]  ++(-\connectlength,0) coordinate (oben_slave1);
    \draw ($(slave1.south west)!.5!(slave1.west)$) to[short,-o] ++(-\connectlength,0) coordinate (unten_slave1);

    % how to change the following line to make the connections look upwards?
    \draw ($(slave2.west north)!.5!(slave2.north)$) to[short,-o]  ++(-\connectlength,0) coordinate (oben_slave2);
    \draw ($(slave2.east north)!.5!(slave2.north)$) to[short,-o] ++(-\connectlength,0) coordinate (unten_slave2);



    \draw (oben_master) to[short] (oben_slave1);
    \draw (unten_master) to[short](unten_slave1);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

i hope you can understand my problem.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, there is no anchor `west north` or `east north`. And second, the lines for the connections must go up, so it should be `++(0,\connectlength)`.

The I also changed `to[...]` to `--`, because for straight lines `--` is prefered. The option for the arrow tip can be given as `\draw[-o] ...`.

I also added the lines from `slave2` to the lines between `master` and `slave1`. Here `-Circle` produces a filled circle as arrow tip and `shorten >=1.8pt` makes the line a bit longer so the circle sits on the horizontal line and not below it (the value was determined by trial and error). The notetion `($(B)!(A)!(C)$)` gives the point on the line `(B) -- (C)` where a line from `(A)` is perpendicular to `(B) -- (C)` (see section 13.5.5 of the PGF manual version 3.0.1a).

All this results in:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
%\usepackage{flowchart}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning, shapes, matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\newcommand{\mysize}{2.5cm}
\newcommand{\connectlength}{0.6cm}

\tikzstyle{mynode}=[draw, minimum size=\mysize,
    label={[anchor = east]25:$\text{A}$},
    label={[anchor = east]-25:$\text{B}$},]

\tikzstyle{mynodemirror} = [draw, minimum size=\mysize,
    label={[anchor = west]155:$\text{A}$},
    label={[anchor = west]205:$\text{B}$},]

% adapted angles here
\tikzstyle{mynodebelow} = [draw, minimum size=\mysize,
    label={[anchor = north]117:$\text{A}$},
    label={[anchor = north]63:$\text{B}$}]

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    % Hilfslinien
%   \draw[help lines] (0,-7) grid (7,7);
    \node[mynode] (master) {node 0};
    \node[mynodemirror, right=8cm of master] (slave1)  {node 1};
    \node[mynodebelow, below left=2.0cm of slave1] (slave2)  {node 2};
%   \node[vcc, above=2cm of slave1]          (nodevcc) {VCC};

    \draw[-o] ($(master.north east)!.5!(master.east)$) --  ++(\connectlength,0) coordinate (oben_master);
    \draw[-o] ($(master.south east)!.5!(master.east)$) -- ++(\connectlength,0) coordinate (unten_master);

    \draw[-o] ($(slave1.north west)!.5!(slave1.west)$) --  ++(-\connectlength,0) coordinate (oben_slave1);
    \draw[-o] ($(slave1.south west)!.5!(slave1.west)$) -- ++(-\connectlength,0) coordinate (unten_slave1);

    \draw[-o] ($(slave2.north west)!.5!(slave2.north)$) --  ++(0,\connectlength) coordinate (oben_slave2);
    \draw[-o] ($(slave2.north east)!.5!(slave2.north)$) -- ++(0,\connectlength) coordinate (unten_slave2);

    \draw (oben_master)  -- (oben_slave1);
    \draw (unten_master) -- (unten_slave1);

    \draw[-Circle,shorten >=-1.8pt] (oben_slave2)  -- ($(oben_master)!(oben_slave2)!(oben_slave1)$);
    \draw[-Circle,shorten >=-1.8pt] (unten_slave2) -- ($(unten_master)!(unten_slave2)!(unten_slave1)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you it helped me alot. i quite didn't understand the syntax. do you know it is in the pgf manual?

Comment: found it. it's called partway modifiers.

Answer (score 2):

with use of small pictures `pic` code for drawing of your picture is simple:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzset{
base/.style = {draw, minimum size=22mm},
  xs/.style = {xshift=#1mm},
  ys/.style = {yshift=#1mm},
    NR/.pic = {\node (@nr) [base] {#1};
        \draw[-o] ([ys=+3] @nr.east) node[left] {A}
        -- ++ (4mm,0) coordinate  (-A);
        \draw[-o] ([ys=-3] @nr.east) node[left] {B}
        -- ++ (4mm,0) coordinate  (-B);
                },
    NL/.pic = {\node (@nr) [base] {#1};
        \draw[-o] ([ys=+3] @nr.west) node[right] {A}
        -- ++ (-4mm,0) coordinate  (-A);
        \draw[-o] ([ys=-3] @nr.west) node[right] {B}
        -- ++ (-4mm,0) coordinate  (-B);
                },
    NA/.pic = {\node (@nr) [base] {#1};
        \draw[-o] ([xs=-3] @nr.north) node[below] {A}
        -- ++ (0,4mm) coordinate  (-A);
        \draw[-o] ([xs=+3] @nr.north) node[below] {B}
        -- ++ (0,4mm) coordinate  (-B);
                }
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (n1) {NR=node 0};
\pic (n2) at (6, 0) {NL=node 0};
\pic (n3) at (3,-4) {NA=node 0};
\draw (n1-A) -- (n2-A);
\draw (n1-B) -- (n2-B);
%
\draw[fill] (n3-A) -- (n1-A -| n3-A) circle (1pt);
\draw[fill] (n3-B) -- (n1-B -| n3-B) circle (1pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]